# VBA: How can I skip rows containing not containing "A" while in a nested loop?

Tags: vba, loops, nested

I am relatively new to VBA.

I have 2 files: (1) Master file (2) Monthly Stats file. I am trying to loop through a column in the Master File to see if it corresponds with the Monthly file. If it matches, then extract the name from Master file. However, there are a lot of N/A inputs in the column, and I only want to loop through rows that start with the string "A". As I already have a nested loop, I cannot type another Next A. Here is my code:

```
Sub SummaryData()

Dim CustCode As String
Dim CustName As String
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim Count As Integer

Workbooks.Open Filename:=Sh_Source.Range("HKS").Value

Set wkb = Workbooks("DataHK.xlsx")

For A = 2 To Sh_Main.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
    If Left(Range("E" & A).Value, 1) = "A" Then
    CustCode = Sh_Main.Range("E" & A).Value
    
    Else
    'Not sure what to put'
    
    Count = 0
    CustName = ""
        
        For b = 2 To wkb.Sheets("Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                
            X = wkb.Sheets("Data").Range("C" & b).Value
                
            If CustCode = X Then
                CustName = Sh_Main.Range("F" & A).Value
                Count = Count + 1
            
            Else
            End If
            Next b
      
     Sh_Body.Range("A" & A).Value = CustCode
     Sh_Body.Range("B" & A).Value = CustName
     Sh_Body.Range("C" & A).Value = Count
     
Next A

wkb.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to this, thank you!

Comment: Hi Bruce! Thank you for your reply. For wkb sheet, every row starts with A. Only the Master sheet Sh_Main contains rows with NA

Comment: When working with more than one workbooks you must be sure to fully qualify each worksheet you address as to which workbook it is in. Your code refers to `Sh_Source` and `Sh_Main` but ineither one is qualified. Therefore both of them are presumed to be in the `ActiveWorkbook` which isn't declared. Start with declaring variables for both sheets with `Dim` statements. Then assign the sheets to the declared variables and refer to them by their declared names.

Comment: From your code it's impossible to know which workbook contains the code, Master or Monthly. Based on syntax,`Sh_Source` is a tab's `CodeName` or a sheet otherwise previously assigned to this name. It must be in the ActiveWorkbook, which might not be the workbook containing the code. Therefore it's impossible to know where it is. I also doubt that you have intended to use `CodeName`s and a worksheet codenamed *Sh_Source* may not exist anywhere. If so, there should be code assigning a particular sheet in a specified workbook to this name before you can retrieve range values from it.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is skip the rest of the current iteration of the loop, you could use `goto`.  I know people dislike it, but it can be simpler than other solutions.  In this case, put `skip:` right above the `Next A` line, and then in your else condition put `goto skip` where you have 'Not sure what to put' and then close your if statement, like this:

```
    If Left(Range("E" & A).Value, 1) = "A" Then
        CustCode = Sh_Main.Range("E" & A).Value
    Else
        Goto skip
    End if
```

so that the whole code would be

```
Sub SummaryData()

Dim CustCode As String
Dim CustName As String
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim Count As Integer

Workbooks.Open Filename:=Sh_Source.Range("HKS").Value

Set wkb = Workbooks("DataHK.xlsx")

For A = 2 To Sh_Main.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
    If Left(Range("E" & A).Value, 1) = "A" Then
        CustCode = Sh_Main.Range("E" & A).Value
    Else
        Goto skip
    End If
    
    Count = 0
    CustName = ""
        
        For b = 2 To wkb.Sheets("Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                
            X = wkb.Sheets("Data").Range("C" & b).Value
                
            If CustCode = X Then
                CustName = Sh_Main.Range("F" & A).Value
                Count = Count + 1
            
            Else
            End If
            Next b
      
     Sh_Body.Range("A" & A).Value = CustCode
     Sh_Body.Range("B" & A).Value = CustName
     Sh_Body.Range("C" & A).Value = Count
     
     skip:
     
Next A

wkb.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Generally people avoid goto (for some good reasons and some bad ones), but I do think that it can be useful and I don't think it's inherently bad.  However, most people in your case would put the entire block inside the if statement, like this:

```
Sub SummaryData()

Dim CustCode As String
Dim CustName As String
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim Count As Integer

Workbooks.Open Filename:=Sh_Source.Range("HKS").Value
Set wkb = Workbooks("DataHK.xlsx")

For A = 2 To Sh_Main.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
    If Left(Range("E" & A).Value, 1) = "A" Then
    
        CustCode = Sh_Main.Range("E" & A).Value
        Count = 0
        CustName = ""
        
        For b = 2 To wkb.Sheets("Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                
            X = wkb.Sheets("Data").Range("C" & b).Value
                
            If CustCode = X Then
                CustName = Sh_Main.Range("F" & A).Value
                Count = Count + 1
            End If
            
            Next b
      
     Sh_Body.Range("A" & A).Value = CustCode
     Sh_Body.Range("B" & A).Value = CustName
     Sh_Body.Range("C" & A).Value = Count
     
    End If
     
Next A

wkb.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

And then the code inside the if block will only execute if the condition is met and there's no need to try to skip the rest of the for loop.

I will note that some of your variables don't seem* to refer to anything, particularly the sheet? variables: Sh_Source, Sh_Main, and Sh_Body.  Without providing a reference for those, this code will fail.

- it's possible they are defined outside of the sub you have provided